# SQL select in n to m relationship

Tags: sql

I have an *n-to-m* relationship between `Author` and `Book`.

**Table Author**

```
ID       Name
1        Follett  
2        Rowling
3        Martin
```

**Table Book**

```
ID     Title                       Category 
1        A Dance with Dragons      Fantasy
2        Harry Potter              Fantasy
3        The Key to Rebecca        Thriller
4        World without end         Drama
```

**Table book_author**

```
authorId       bookId
1        3  
2        2
3        1
1        4
```

There are a lot more authors and books in the system. Now I want to select all authors that have a book in genre "*Fantasy*".

This is what I came up so far with:

```
   select distinct a.id 
   from author a, book b, written w 
   where w.authorId = a.id and w.bookId = b.id and b.category = "Fantasy";
```

I am wondering how to optimize this query since especially table book is really large.

Comment: Do your tables have indexes? On which columns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is recommended to use an explicit `JOIN` instead of the implicit (comma-separated table list) join you currently have, as it will improve flexibility if and when you need to introduce left joins.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT a.id
FROM
  author a
  JOIN book_author ba ON a.id = ba.authorId
  JOIN books b ON b.id = ba.bookId
WHERE b.category = 'Fantasy'
```

If your `book_author` has defined `FOREIGN KEY`  relationships back to the `author` and `books` tables, indexes will be enforced. Likewise, the respective `id` columns in those tables should be defined as `PRIMARY KEY`.  Beyond this, the only potential optimization you can do is to create an index on `books.category`.

```
CREATE TABLE book_author (
  authorId INT NOT NULL, /* or whatever the data type... */
  bookId INT NOT NULL,
  /* define FK constraints in book_author */
  FOREIGN KEY (authorId) REFERENCES author (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (bookId) REFERENCES books (id)
);
```

Comment: hi. Wow, fast reply :). Thank you for the answer. I actually already have the fk's defined like this and the referenced values are primary key. Thanks for your valuable help, will use the explicit joins.

Comment: +1 for recommending index on books.category. Also category should be a separated table in order to avoid repeating the name of the category in hundreds of rows.

Comment: The index on category exists :). I highly simplified the example to be able to ask an understandable question, so the category isn't really repeated that many times. Thanks for the input.