# (sqlite with PDO) How do I get the associated data from pivot table?

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Firstly, I'm not sure if pivot table is the correct term so apologies for that.

I've been given a database that has a table `Users_Photos` with 1 column being `User_ID` and the other `Photo_ID`.

I need to do a query with PDO that will return each row from the `Users` table as an assoc array and, where a `Photo` for the `User` exists add to it a `images` key thats value would be an array of uris from the `uri` column on the table `Photos`. (A user may have many photos).

I'm sure the answer lies somewhere with SQL joins and I've been looking into that but I can't find an example on how to do that from a table that only has the 2 ids. The `Users` and `Photos` tables do not have a reference to each other on their respective tables, just on the `Users_Photos` table.

Comment: This question may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824087/sql-select-in-n-to-m-relationship

Comment: pivot = taking rows of a result and turning them into columns, or vice versa.